# Puppeteer redirect throws ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: redirect, google-chrome-extension, error-handling, puppeteer, interception

I am using puppeteer to bring up chromium and launch a page. For my scenario the page URL has to be intercepted along with the css/js/img requests coming from the page.

My puppeteer code for page interception looks like this,

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on("request", async (request: HTTPRequest) => {
  if (request.url().endsWith(".html") || 
      request.url().endsWith(".js") || 
      request.url().endsWith(".css") ||
      request.url().endsWith(".png")) {
    let redirectUrl = await getNewUrl(request.url());
    request.continue({ url: redirectUrl });
  } else {
    request.continue();
  }
}
```

1. My initial HTML page load happens properly with the redirect URL.
2. Then the HTML page has a few browser requests the redirect URL is also fetched and the request is continued with redirect URL.

All the browser requests return an error looking like this,
[image]

I am still new to puppeteer and chrome extension development, kindly let me know if any way to figure out the issue here.

Comment: Usually `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` comes when your resource is blocked by a Chrome extension. Are you sure the URL is correct and can you check by disabling extensions?

Comment: The URL is correct and verified it. If I copy the URL of the `thumb.png` that you see in the screenshot above and run it on the same page, the redirection happens properly and the image(from the redirected URL) comes up with no issues.

Comment: Do you mind joining [this slack channel](https://requestlycommunity.slack.com/join/shared_invite/zt-113lursq9-2TI4bXLhkdNPEpTUJBprIA#/shared-invite/email) I'd be interested in seeing this over a call and helping you debug it? We can coordinate on slack about the meeting time.

Answer (score 0):

I am also suffering from same issue but I have a solution for this issue. If you are using ajax method and give static url path so remove this path and fix from dynamic path.

Comment: Hi Mohit are you still having suffer from this `Puppeteer` redirect throwing `ERR_BLOCK_BY_CLIENT`? Or does this solution make this go away. Regardless can you please provide more information to your answer? Ideally a code sample that includes your solution with some comments to what it's doing. Thanks o:)